# How to create in-app-subscriptions through code in flutter?

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, google-play-console, in-app-subscription

I want to implement profile subscription in my flutter app. Where users can subscribe to creator accounts to see their premium content. So how can I dynamically create a subscription product in my play console when a user registers as a creator account?

I created three subscription products in play console. The creator will select package they want for their subscription. But when a normal user subscribe a creator profile for Package_A (for example) if the other creator has also selected Package_A, the normal user will be subscribed to the other creator too as he/she subscribed that package already.